# Error: Mage registry key "_singleton/mage_gextorshop/observer" already exists

Tags: magento-1.9, register, singleton

*(Sorry if my english is bad, but is not my language)*

My Magento version is 1.9.3.8

I tried to solved this error whit this in SSH:

```
php -f shell/compiler.php disable
php -f shell/compiler.php clear
php -f shell/compiler.php compile
```

But didnt work (with compile, and without it).

This is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Gextorshop>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mage_Gextorshop>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mage_gextorshop>
                <class>Mage_GextorShop_Model</class>
            </mage_gextorshop>
        </models>
                <helpers>
                        <mage_gextorshop>
                                <class>mage_gextorshop_Helper</class>
                        </mage_gextorshop>
                </helpers>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <mage_gextorshop>
                        <class>mage_gextorshop/observer</class>
                        <method>logUpdate</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </mage_gextorshop>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

In LocalHost had the same problem and when I used the SSH commands, solved it.
Also I uninstalled the custom module, used SSH commands and installed again the module but error continue.

Other similar questions that I found didnt help me.

Comment: Disable compilation, flush and clear the cache then try again. I would suggest you to check in includes/config.php all code should commented  after fire that disable compilation command.

Comment: Code from includes/config.php is commented, but error still happens.

Comment: Just backup the var/cache and session folder then delete them try again after that in private browser window.

Comment: Same as always... error still there.

Comment: Try with '<type>model</type>' instead of '<type>singleton</type>'.

Comment: I supose I will need to use `Mage::getModel` instead of `Mage::getSingleton` in Observer.php right?

Comment: I mean in your xml where you are configured observer. Some time singleton creates error.

Comment: I have added it in answer. Please accept it so it will help to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Gextorshop>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mage_Gextorshop>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mage_gextorshop>
                <class>Mage_GextorShop_Model</class>
            </mage_gextorshop>
        </models>
                <helpers>
                        <mage_gextorshop>
                                <class>mage_gextorshop_Helper</class>
                        </mage_gextorshop>
                </helpers>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <mage_gextorshop>
                        <class>mage_gextorshop/observer</class>
                        <method>logUpdate</method>
                        <type>model</type>
                    </mage_gextorshop>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```